# При поиске текста регулярными выражениями съедает первый символ ненужной строки и вставляет в результат

Tags: python, re

Задача: Найти те строки, которые не соответствуют конкретной строке.
В итоге регулярки находят эту строку которую нужно проигнорировать как и положено, но возвращают вместе со всем результатом, только без первого символа.

```
import re
ratio = '53064241:41,82104212:13,'
us = '82104212'
last = re.findall(r'(?!{value})+[\d]+:[\d\-]+'.format(value=us), ratio)
```

Вывод от принта `(print(last))`

['53064241:41', '2104212:13']

Пилю свой первый проект, потому опыта ещё нет. Помогите пожалуйста.
P.S. Форматирование строки обусловлено тем что значения будут постоянно меняться.

Comment: вы уверены, что вам нужна регулярка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае будет быстрее и эффективнее воспользоваться стандартными методами python:

```
ratio = '53064241:41,82104212:13,'
us = '82104212'
res = [x for x in ratio.rstrip(",").split(",") if us not in x.split(":")]
```

res:

```
['53064241:41']
```

Если вы все-таки хотите использовать регулярки, то, скорее всего, так ваш код будет работать:

```
import re
ratio = '53064241:41,82104212:13,91514209:41,9999999999999:41,82104212:--'
us = '82104212'
last = re.findall(r'\b((?!{value})[\d]+:[\d\-]+)\b'.format(value=us), ratio)
```

last:

```
['53064241:41', '91514209:41', '9999999999999:41']
```

Comment: Благодарю! Проверил оба метода. Всё работает. Только во втором варианте (с регулярками), по какой то причине выдаёт только первый результат и останавливается. Для теста добавил '91514209:41' и уже это он не находит.

Comment: я поправил ответ.